# PandasのDataFrame.concatメソッドのsort引数の意味、効果は？

Tags: python, python3, pandas

PandasのDataFrame.concatメソッドのsort引数にTrueを指定しても、（sort=Falseを指定しても）
実行結果に変化が見られないのですが、
どのような効果がるのでしょうか？

Pandasの公式ドキュメントは読んだのですが、理解できませんでした。
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'A': ['A2', 'A3'],
        'B': ['B2', 'B3']
    },
    index=[2, 3]
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
        'B': ['B0', 'B1']},
    index=[0, 1]
)

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)  # ←sort引数はどのような効果があるのでしょうか？
display(result)

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=True)  # ←sort引数はどのような効果があるのでしょうか？
display(result)

result = result.sort_index()
display(result)  # ←sort=Trueとしたときの期待していた結果です。
```

以下、実行結果です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事に書いてあるように、列名をソートするかどうかだと思われます。[実際の例：カラムの順番のみが異なる場合](https://qiita.com/greenteabiscuit/items/1c950d94d8f9156ace10#%E5%AE%9F%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%8B%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E9%A0%86%E7%95%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%8C%E7%95%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88), [python pandas concatについてのメモ](https://ken26u.blog/python/2020-02-18-231259/2020/02/18/)

Comment: リンクありがとうございます。理解できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

行のソートではなく列の表示順をソートするかしないかを指定できるようです。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'B': ['B2', 'B3'],
        'A': ['A2', 'A3'],
    },
    index=[2, 3]
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
        'B': ['B0', 'B1']},
    index=[0, 1]
)

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
print(result)
#    B   A
#2  B2  A2
#3  B3  A3
#0  B0  A0
#1  B1  A1

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=True)
print(result)
#    A   B
#2  A2  B2
#3  A3  B3
#0  A0  B0
#1  A1  B1
```

Comment: 理解できましたありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

参考情報として。

[pandas.concat — pandas 2.0.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

> ```
> sort: bool, default False
>
>     Sort non-concatenation axis if it is not already aligned.
> ```

**non-concatenation axis** と記載されているので、`axis=1`(列方向に結合)を指定するとインデックス(行)がソートされます。(無論、期待する結果にはなりませんが)

```py
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=True)

#      A    B    A    B
# 0  NaN  NaN   A0   B0
# 1  NaN  NaN   A1   B1
# 2   A2   B2  NaN  NaN
# 3   A3   B3  NaN  NaN
```